# LIBSVM Python ctypes string function pointer segmentation faults

Tags: python, machine-learning, solaris, ctypes, libsvm

I've been porting a Python package that uses libsvm onto some production servers and ran into a strange segmentation fault which I traced to a ctypes function pointer. I'm trying to determine where the ctypes wrapper failed and if this is a distro specific problem or not.

The system I am running this on is a very clean virtual machine with almost nothing installed:
Solaris 5.11
amd64 pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
Python 2.7.2

Now for the problem description and how I narrowed to ctypes. In libsvm you can specify the print function by passing a `void (*print_func)(const char *)` pointer into the `svm_set_print_string_function` function. The default with a NULL pointer is to print to stdout. Now the interesting part is that the Python wrapper for libsvm (which works fine on a variety of other systems) makes such a function pointer when asking for quiet mode (no printing) via the following:

```
PRINT_STRING_FUN = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p)
def print_null(s): 
    return

if argv[i] == "-q":
    self.print_func = PRINT_STRING_FUN(print_null)

libsvm.svm_set_print_string_function(self.print_func)
```

When I set quiet mode libsvm accepts the function pointer but hangs after a few seconds when calling `svm_train` then seg faults. I tried making a `void *` argument function pointer and then casting it to a `const char *` function pointer with the same results, which means it wasn't the conversion from `const char *` to a PyStringObject.

Then I finally just wrote a C++ function to set the function pointer to a no-op in the library itself by:

```
void print_null(const char *) {}

void svm_set_print_null() {
    svm_set_print_string_function(&print_null);
}
```

which worked as expected with no segmentation faults. This leads me to think that the ctypes is failing at some internal point of function pointer conversion. Looking through the ctypes source files hasn't revealed anything obvious to me though I haven't worked a lot with ctypes explicitly so it's difficult to narrow down where the bug might be.

I can use my library addition solution for now, but if I want to silently process the returns I would need to actually be able to pass a function pointer into libsvm. Plus it doesn't give me peace of mind about stability if I need to implement such workarounds without knowing what's the true root cause of the problem.

Has anyone else had problems with libsvm print functions on Solaris or specifically ctypes function pointers in Python on Solaris? I couldn't find anything searching online about either such problems with Solaris. I planning on playing around with library calls and making some function processing libs to find the exact boundaries of failure, but someone else's input might save me a day or two of debug testing.

**UPDATE**

The problem is reproducible on the 32bit version of Solaris 5.11 as well.

Comment: I've had issues similar to what you describe with ctypes and function pointers, but on Windows, not Solaris.  I could step through the C code in gdb and could verify that it was the calling back into Python that caused the crash.  I didn't look into it much as it was difficult to put together an SSCCE.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Which version of Windows was it out of curiosity? I am so far only able to reproduce the problem on Solaris machines.

Comment: it was Windows 7 Professional x64, with 32-bit Python 2.7.2.

Comment: It might be a 2.7.2 bug -- I found in 2.7.3 changelog: Issue #7959, Issue #12483 and Bug #1701409 all addressing cytpes errors that could create the problem I am seeing. Unfortunately compiling 2.7.3 from source is failing to build the _ctypes submodule on Solaris so I am having a hard time confirming.

Comment: When you use callback functions the Python object wrapping the function must exist for the lifetime that the callback is called. It looks like you are assigning the object to an attribute of a class (`self.print_func`) but does that object continue to exist after `svm_set_print_string_function` is called?

Comment: @MarkTolonen That's a good point. But yes, the object holding print_func is made in the function `train` and continues to be alive for the duration of that function call. When the function `train` ends then the object has no references, but it's only used inside of `train`.